# Getting data from server in browser without making a request

Tags: javascript, httpserver

I've a Javascript app(Not a Node.js one, actually runs on Apache Httpd) which has to recieve data from custom server. So my server sends a post request and i've to recieve it client side javascript. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: AJAX will simplify your life to do that. Check this link: http://fr.openclassrooms.com/informatique/cours/un-site-web-dynamique-avec-jquery/le-fonctionnement-de-ajax

Comment: In HTTP protocol, only client can request data from server, server can not contact client.

Comment: Agree with @CarlSmith.. Websockets can be used

Answer (score 0):

If only your server is able to fetch that data, then you can bootstrap it in your template:

Pseudo code, assuming php is used:

```
<head>
    <script>
        echo( 'var obj=' . $my_fetched_value . ';' );
    </script>
</head>
```

Then in your whatever script:

```
console.log( obj );
```